# ¡Remix Run no inicia! (TypeError: isbot is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy iniciando con Remix Run y le doy al comando de instalación que me da la docu oficial:

> npx create-remix@latest

Me tira por consola:

```
Watching Remix app in development mode...
 Built in 3.2s
Remix App Server started at http://localhost:3000 (http://192.168.56.1:3000)
TypeError: isbot is not a function
    at handleRequest (C:\Users\....)
    at handleDocumentRequest (C:\Users\..
etc.etc. se repite lo mismo varias veces...
```

En el navegador me tira:

```
Unexpected Server Error
TypeError: isbot is not a function
```

Mi version de node es: 16.10.0
de npm: 7.24.0

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un problema similar, y pude resolverlo borrando la caché con el siguiente comando:

```bash
npm cache clean --force
```

luego utiliza nuevamente

```bash
npx create-remix@latest
```